# Finding rig gap specifications of old engine

Tags: small-engine, piston, torque-specification

I am currently restoring an old Briggs & Stratton engine. I found that it burns a little bit of oil and also saw that the head was oily after removal. I removed the piston and checked the ring gap in the cylinder. In my opinion it was definitely too large (larger than my feeler gauge could measure). However I was trying to look up the actual specifications for the gaps (as well as torque specs for the crank case bolts) online but I am having a tough time finding anything. With the model number I was able to find a parts list but any sort of specifications seems a dead end. I have only been working on engines for a year or so, therefore I am still lacking a lot of handy tricks.

My question is therefore, how does one usually obtain information beyond just the user manual for older engines before the age of the internet (the engine is from 1984)?

Secondary question in case there is no general answer for the first one: Does anyone know the various torque and ring specs for a briggs & stratton engine model 132232-2036-1? All I can find are parts lists :(

Comment: Typically (depending on manufacturer) the **minimal** amount of ring gap is .004" per inch of cylinder diameter, but I don't see anything which states what the maximum ring gap can be before it's too much. I've seen mentioned as much as 0.125" of end gap is still viable, though I'd never run an 1/8" of gap in anything I can think of. I'll keep looking.

Comment: I have to measure the bore, I cant even find any manual specifying this basic information, in fact the briggs & stratton website says no documents exist for that model number... I also talked to a friend doing engine repair professionally and he also didnt have any manuals. That sucks... I did order a set of new rings anyway, Ill see if it looks any different when they get here.

Comment: I discovered many sources of free info when attempting to troubleshoot a '70s Sears 1.5 ton floor jack. Apparently made in Japan with several online/youtube sources for rebuilding. Parts are plentiful as this is one of many standard floor jacks. Based on this, I would guess B&S engines would have at least a few online/youtube sources of help in restoring old engines as long as parts are available. Someone somewhere is willing to share info.